# Why gradle build is failing with UndeclaredThrowableException?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I have tried changing the gradle settings and build.gradle files. Also tried changing Java Compiler settings in Android stuido and updating the JDK and Android Studio.

Here's a reproducible 5.5MB github repo: https://github.com/AnimusPetitor/plusrepr

./gradlew build

**output:**

```
> Configure project :TMessagesProj
The setTestClassesDir(File) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the setTestClassesDirs(FileCollection) method instead.
The getTestClassesDir() method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the getTestClassesDirs() method instead.
The ConfigurableReport.setDestination(Object) method has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the method ConfigurableReport.setDestination(File) instead.

> Task :TMessagesProj:processArmv7DebugGoogleServices
Parsing json file: /home/elanimus/Desktop/plus-messenger-master-1d96151861d0db96ffe384807621a0a3a2d371c8/TMessagesProj/google-services.json


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':TMessagesProj:compileArmv7DebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 48s
36 actionable tasks: 36 executed
```

Comment: I've found the problem. The files inside the project had incorrect permissions. I chowned the project with: 'chown -R elanimus:elanums .'. elanimus is Linux's username

Comment: You can post it as answer

Answer (score 1):

I've found the problem. The files inside the project had incorrect permissions. I chowned the project with: 'chown -R elanimus:elanums .'. elanimus is Linux's username